# Make boxes appear in continuous order when wrapped around corners (left-to-right, down, then right-to-left)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to make a bunch of distinct boxes to wrap around the page but preserve the order by not jumping from right to left but start from right to left..

So instead of

```
A B C D E

F G H I
```

it should be like

```
A B C D E

  I H G F
```

The boxes are all `inline-block` elements.

Comment: show your code which you tried sofar?

Comment: @Kiran I have no idea how to approach this, whatsoever. Google turned up no results either.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/AxjC2/1/)**

html

```
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
<div>D</div>
<div>E</div>
<div>F</div>
<div>G</div>
<div>H</div>
```

css

```
div {
    width: calc(25% - 2px); /* adjust borders */
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    display: inline;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    color: white;
    float: left;
}
body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div:nth-child(n+4) {
    float: right; /* this will make things as required */
}
```

Comment: Small fix needed. With Desired result you should apply 20% width for div and nth-child should be n+5.